# Stack Rank numbers suddenly messed up in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

I don't know if it is related in some way to TFS 2013 Udpate 2 that I performed recently but suddenly many Stack Rank numbers we set manually are messed up and got very high random value.

I have just started using TFS in my daily work and I would like to know if I this behavior is a bug or is considered correct. In the second case is there an option to set in order to avoid this automatic numbering?

[image]

Comment: What do you expect them to be, 162, 486 and 540? Can you reproduce this issue on by updating a TFS 2013 Update 1 running on a backup of your database?

Comment: No, I am used to write very low Stack Rank values, between 1 and 5 till now. At the moment I don't have many issues so I can easily fix the values manually, I just would like to know if TFS use some auto numbering algorithm in some situation and if there is the possibility to disable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ewald explains everything in this post [Behind the scenes: the Backlog Priority or Stack Rank field](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/behind-the-scenes-the-backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-field/)

> After we shipped the change, we have received multiple reports from
> customers who were confused with the change. If the customer had set
> the Backlog Priority field via Excel to values 1..N, the old
> sparsification logic kept the range values pretty much intact
> (especially the top items). With Update 2 however, once you add or
> reorder items on the backlog, the sparsification logic sets the field
> values to big numbers to introduce big gaps, and give you good
> performance. This change is intentionally, and by design. The Backlog
> Priority field was always intended to be a system field, and our
> recommendation is to not update field manually.  You can still use
> Excel to quickly set the order of the backlog with the values 1..N,
> but be aware that the sparsification will kick in. And although the
> values are different, the order of the items on the backlog are still
> the same!

Comment: But the Stack Rank field is editable by the user, if it is a system field why is there? Is there another user field that I can use instead of Stack Rank for User Stories in order to prioritize them?

Comment: If the field was not editable, users' would not be able to rearrange items. IIRC is the Order field that you use for hard sort.

Comment: The field is visible on the form so that you can do some high grained ordering. If you find something you like at the bottom of the backlog it is hard to get it to the top by dragging. Pop a 1 in there and then fine-tune at the top...

Comment: The field has been removed from the work item UI in Update 4 of TFS 2013.

Answer (score 2):

The weird numbers are appearing when you use the keyboard or the drag-drop to prioritize the PBIs.
A better explanation is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/05/14/behind-the-scenes-the-backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-field.aspx)

Comment: I didn't even know that I could use drag&drop o keyboard to change the Stack Rank fields, maybe my colleagues did it. Any possibility to block auto numbering?

Comment: You can see in the history of the work item who changed the Stack Rank field. In the ProcessConfiguration file you have <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" type="Order" /> line; as you drag items the background process updates the field that is marked with Type=Order

Comment: I just tried this - you have to be in Backlog view, it doesn't work on the Board (I'm using 2013 update 4) - and it finally made the sparse ranking make sense to me. I always tried dragging in Board view, and never tried in Backlog view, and i think this will actually work.