# TFS Drag and Drop Priority Broken on Kanban board

Tags: tfs

I am new to TFS (coming from a JIRA background) and have been learning to administrate the system via XML documents.  I started by copying the Agile template and modifying it for my needs.  Somewhere along the way I must have broken the Kanban Drag-and-Drop for prioritizing the backlog items, but I have no idea how I broke it or how to fix it.

I am working in a custom Project Template and periodically uploading it to the server to validate that nothing is so broken that it is rejected.

I guess my question is, do I need to use a certain field in the WIT in order to enable the Drag-and-Drop or is it supposed to just work out of the box?  I did add a field for **Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank** but that didn't do the trick.

In case it isn't clear, here is a quick screen grab of the issue: [TFS Drag-and-Drop Broken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2qJ0VV6JuM)

Right now I have about a week of work (and learning) into this project template and REALLY don't want to have to start from scratch just to fix the Drag-and-Drop.  Any advice from a more experienced admin would be greatly appreciated.  Specifically this is TFS 2013.

#### XML related to stack rank in the WIT:

```
<FIELD name="Stack Rank" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" type="Double" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>Work first on items with lower-valued stack rank. Set in Backlog.</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that TFS has never allowed drag-and-drop re-ordering on the kanban board, it is only from the Backlog page.  Coming from JIRA just had my expectations set incorrectly.  All is right with the world.

Comment: Just to give you heads up of a common issue, since you're customizing the project template, do not try to implement external logic using stack rank; it is automatically regenerated using drag&drop by tfs in the background. More detail in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202345/stack-rank-numbers-suddenly-messed-up-in-tfs-2013)

Comment: Thanks @BeytanKurt, I appreciate the warning!  I hadn't quite made it that far yet, but I'm sure I would have stepped right into that hole.